# Getting Limited number of columns of a table using javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a table where td is dynamically generated

```
   <table>
   <tr>
      <td>Sample A </td>
      <td>Sample B </td>
      <td>Sample C </td>
      <td>Sample D </td>
      <td>Sample E </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

where Sample A,B,C,D,E Dynamically generated and it also have  F,G,H etc.

Now I want to display only  5 records,not all.whatever records it may be,only 5 records I want to show

Can anyone please help me out in writing javascript code where 6th column will be automatically hide and display only 5 's.

Please some one help me out.

Comment: what you have tried in javascript or other file ?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using jquery. then it'd look something like this

```
<script>
    var cols = $("#myRow").children("td");
    foreach...
</script>
<table>
   <tr id="myRow">
      <td>Sample A </td>
      <td>Sample B </td>
      <td>Sample C </td>
      <td>Sample D </td>
      <td>Sample E </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

see if you can figure out the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are not using jQuery:

```
var cellz = document.getElementById('thistable').rows[0].cells;
    for(i=5; i < cellz.length; i++){
      cellz[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
```

That hides all cells beyond the first 5. Collects the cells in an array, then we loop thru the array and hide those td's that are 5+.

I chose 5 to fit your needs.

here should be your code

```
   <table id="thistable">
     <tr>
       <td>Sample A </td>
       <td>Sample B </td>
       <td>Sample C </td>
       <td>Sample D </td>
       <td>Sample E </td>
     </tr>
   </table>


  <script type="text/javascript">
     // hide td's 5+
     var cellz = document.getElementById('thistable').rows[0].cells;
       for(i=5; i < cellz.length; i++){
       cellz[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: Hello Rich,Thanks for your reply I have applied this but its not working in my side

Comment: It's not my answer I just edited it, but what is the id of your table? This method requires your table to have an id. You need to replace the text 'thistable' with the id of your actual table.

Comment: Saurav, what are you having issues with? Did you apply an Id to the table? See my answer above, I edited it, so just cut/paste it. And like Rich mentions, whatever ID you give your table (I gave it "thistable"), make sure that is the same one in your javascript getElementById('thistable')

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery :gt() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$("table tr").find("td:gt(4), th:gt(4)").hide();
//It will find td and th elements in table at index greater than 4 (column 6, column 7, ...), then hide them
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind dropping support for old browsers, you can use a pure CSS3 solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwj6S/

```css
table#target tr > td:nth-child(n+6) {
    display:none;
}
```

According to this [compatible table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), this will be dropping IE<=8.